# R calculation and plot graph

Tags: r

I am very new in R.

I've got the attached range of data, which is the list of  town council issues:

```
SNO  Dept  FeedbackDate  ClosedDate2        SubCategory1          SubZone
  1   BTA    23/11/2012    4/12/2012  Permission-to-Park   TOWNSVILL EAST
  2   RTA    23/12/2012    4/13/2012              Rodent  TOWNSVILL SOUTH
  3   MTA    23/12/2012    4/16/2012           ConductVL  TOWNSVILL SOUTH
```

I would like to get some insight to show

1) which are departments has higher resolution time(ClosedDate2 - FeedbackDate) for same Subcategory in differnt subzone.

2) resolution time for duplicate Subcategory in different subzone.

Comment: Do you want to create a barchart, with x - SubZone, y - resolution time?
library(ggplot2); resolution.time = ClosedDate2 - FeedbackDate; 
ggplot(data = dataframe.town.council) + geom_bar(aes(x = SubZone, y = resolution.time))

Comment: Not very sure i can use histogram ....want to plot a graph to get some insight to show 1) which are department has higher resolution time for same issue in differnt subzone.2) resolution time for duplicate issues in diffeent timezone.

Comment: it's much easier to help you when you know what you need, can you edit  your question and elaborate more on what you need from R?
There are multiple ways to plot graphics, take a look here - http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

Answer (score 1):

How about this with `dplyr` and `ggplot2`:

I have edited/made up a larger data set to show how it can work:

```
dat<-data.frame(SNO=1:100,
           Dept=sample(c("BTA","RTA","MTA"),100,T),
           FeedbackDate=as.Date("2012/12/23"),
           ClosedDate2=as.Date("2012/12/23")+ceiling(runif(100)*20),
           SubCategory1=sample(c("Permission-to-Park","Rodent","ConductVL"),100,T),
           SubZone=sample(c("TOWNSVILL EAST","TOWNSVILL SOUTH"),100,T))

require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)     #for aggregation

dat.sum<-group_by(dat, SubCategory1, SubZone, Dept) %.%  # group by SC1, SZ and Dept comb
  summarise(AvgResTime=mean(ClosedDate2-FeedbackDate))   # calculate average of closure date for each

ggplot(dat.sum) + #use aggregated dat
  geom_point(aes(x=SubCategory1, y=AvgResTime,color=SubZone),size=10) + # color points by Zone
  facet_wrap(~ Dept) +                                                  # one face per department
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))              # rotate x axis text
```

[image]

updated with `plyr` for your previous version

```
require(plyr)     #for aggregation
dat.sum<-ddply(dat,.(SubCategory1, SubZone, Dept),summarise,AvgResTime=mean(ClosedDate2-FeedbackDate))

ggplot(dat.sum) + #use aggregated dat
  geom_point(aes(x=SubCategory1, y=as.integer(AvgResTime),color=SubZone),size=10) + # color points by Zone
  facet_wrap(~ Dept) +                                                  # one face per department
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))              # rotate x axis text
```

Comment: Troy, thank fors your great help.. but i am unable to run the code I 1) I am currenly using R version 2.14.2 .dplyr is not avialble in my version. 2) Error: could not find function "%.%" 3) Error in ggplot(dat.sum) : object 'dat.sum' not found ... Actually i am not sure i can plot graph cos i have abt 100 or more subcategories.. basically i just need to find the result.. will do ...

Comment: what error code do you get? do you have ggplot2 and plyr packages installed? run
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("plyr")

Comment: I am currenly using R version 2.14.2, so dplyr is not avialble in my version.

Comment: I've updated the text to use `plyr` a previous incarnation of `dplyr`, the dat.sum call is changed, and you also need to force the difftime to be an integer (I've in the ggplot call, but you could do it in ddply)